# Convert string to object hierarchy

Tags: javascript, string, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have the following string returned from an API and I want to convert it to an object hierarchy using javascript.

The string received is:

```
"paymentInfoList.paymentInfo(0).receiver.amount":"12.00"
```

I want to convert it to a javascript object like:

```
{
    paymentInfoList: {
        PaymentInfo: [{
             receiver: {
                 amount: 12.0
             }
        }]
    }
}
```

I could write my own parser but wonder if there is some code already out there.

**Update**

Based on the answer from @JasonCust here is a parser to parse a full response from the PayPal Adaptive Payments Pay method:
https://github.com/danielflippance/paypal-ap-parser

Comment: Is this a standard format? It looks pretty *ad hoc* to me, so I doubt someone has already written code to deal with it.

Comment: If you used JSON there is a built in parser. That however looks like a custom format, so you're going to need to write a custom parser. I'd verify the API your using doesn't have an option to return JSON since it would then be trivial to do. By the way, from your text it's hard to even discern the actual pattern. What if paymentInfo had 2 members, how would it look then?

Comment: It's a format that comes from PayPal Adaptive Payments.

Comment: That expression seems to be some kind of Java expression langauge (EL) generated.  Not sure it can be solved in Javascript

Comment: @DanielFlippance What would be the expected output if `paymentInfo(0)` is, say, `paymentInfo(3)`?

Comment: @Jordan, paymentInfo is an array and the (0) indicates the index in the array.

Comment: Right. So what does the array look like if we only know the value at index 3?

Comment: @Jordan The indexes are always sequencial starting at 0

Comment: What do you mean? Will there be sometimes be more than one index? What would the input and output look like in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of an existing parser that handles that format. Maybe something on Paypal's developer site? If you roll your own you could do so using a recursive function like the example below. I haven't tested it thoroughly but it's a POC that it's easy enough to do.

```
function setObjVal(obj, paths, val) {
  var path;
  var arrayInfo;

  if (paths.length === 0) {
    return val;
  }

  obj = obj || {};
  path = paths.shift();
  arrayInfo = path.match(arrayRegExp);

  if (arrayInfo) {
    path = arrayInfo[1];

    if (!Array.isArray(obj[path])) {
      obj[path] = [];
    }

    obj[path][arrayInfo[2]] = setObjVal(obj[path][arrayInfo[2]], paths, val);
  }
  else {
    obj[path] = setObjVal(obj[path], paths, val);
  }

  return obj;
}
```

```js
var arrayRegExp = /^(\w+)\((\d+)\)$/;

var input = '"paymentInfoList.paymentInfo(0).receiver.amount":"12.00"';
var pair = input.split(':').map(function (str) { return str.replace(/"/g, ''); });
var newObj = setObjVal({}, pair[0].split('.'), pair[1]);

function setObjVal(obj, paths, val) {
  var path;
  var arrayInfo;
  
  if (paths.length === 0) {
    return val;
  }

  obj = obj || {};
  path = paths.shift();
  arrayInfo = path.match(arrayRegExp);
  
  if (arrayInfo) {
    path = arrayInfo[1];
    
    if (!Array.isArray(obj[path])) {
      obj[path] = [];
    }
    
    obj[path][arrayInfo[2]] = setObjVal(obj[path][arrayInfo[2]], paths, val);
  }
  else {
    obj[path] = setObjVal(obj[path], paths, val);
  }
  
  return obj;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newObj, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

**Alternatively** if you want to use lodash you could use [`_.set()`](https://lodash.com/docs#set):

```
var newObj = _.set({}, pair[0].replace(/\(/g, '[').replace(/\)/g, ']'), pair[1]);
```

```js
var input = '"paymentInfoList.paymentInfo(0).receiver.amount":"12.00"';
var pair = input.split(':').map(function (str) { return str.replace(/"/g, ''); });

var newObj = _.set({}, pair[0].replace(/\(/g, '[').replace(/\)/g, ']'), pair[1]);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newObj, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I like your lodash solution.

Comment: @Jordan I do as well but it is fun to occasionally solve puzzles by digging in and rolling your own solution. :-P

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't resist a little puzzle, here's a clean recursive solution that works for the input you've given (scroll down and view the snippet for a little playground):

```
function objectFromExpression(expression, value) {
  if (!expression) {
    return value;
  }

  var obj = {};
  var matchKeyIdxRest = /^(\w+)(?:\((\d+)\))?(?:\.(.+))?$/;
  var matches = expression.match(matchKeyIdxRest);

  if (!matches) {
    throw new Error('Oops! There\'s a problem with the expression at "' + expression + '"');
  }

  var key = matches[1];
  var idx = matches[2];
  var rest = matches[3];
  var next = objectFromExpression(rest, value);

  if (idx) {
    var arr = [];
    arr[ parseInt(idx) ] = next;
    obj[key] = arr;
  } else {
    obj[key] = next;
  }

  return obj;
}

function keyValueExpressionToKeyValue(str) {
  var matchKeyVal = /^"([^"]+)":"([^"]+)"$/;
  var matches = str.match(matchKeyVal);

  if (!matches) {
    throw new Error('Oops! Couldn\'t extract key and value from input!');
  }

  return matches.slice(1);
}

var input = '"paymentInfoList.paymentInfo(0).receiver.amount":"12.00"';
var keyAndValue = keyValueExpressionToKeyValue(input);
var key = keyAndValue[0];   // => paymentInfoList.paymentInfo(0).receiver.amount
var value = keyAndValue[1]; // => 12.00

objectFromExpression(key, value);
// => { paymentInfoList:
//      { paymentInfo:
//        [ { receiver:
//            { amount: "12.00" }
//          }
//        ]
//      }
//    }
```

```js
function objectFromExpression(expression, value) {
  if (!expression) {
    return value;
  }

  var obj = {};
  var matchKeyIdxRest = /^(\w+)(?:\((\d+)\))?(?:\.(.+))?$/;
  var matches = expression.match(matchKeyIdxRest);

  if (!matches) {
    throw new Error('Oops! There\'s a problem with the expression at "' + expression + '"');
  }

  var key = matches[1];
  var idx = matches[2];
  var rest = matches[3];
  var next = objectFromExpression(rest, value);

  if (idx) {
    var arr = [];
    arr[ parseInt(idx) ] = next;
    obj[key] = arr;
  } else {
    obj[key] = next;
  }

  return obj;
}

function keyValueExpressionToKeyValue(str) {
  var matchKeyVal = /^"([^"]+)":"([^"]+)"$/;
  var matches = str.match(matchKeyVal);

  if (!matches) {
    throw new Error('Oops! Couldn\'t extract key and value from input!');
  }

  return matches.slice(1);
}

var inputEl = document.getElementById('input');

function onKeyUp() {
  var outputEl = document.getElementById('output');
  var input = inputEl.value.trim();

  try {
    var keyAndValue = keyValueExpressionToKeyValue(input);
    var key = keyAndValue[0];
    var value = keyAndValue[1];

    var output = objectFromExpression(key, value);
    outputEl.value = JSON.stringify(output, null, 2);
  } catch (ex) {
    outputEl.value = ex.toString();
  }
}

inputEl.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
inputEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup'));
```

```css
label, textarea, input { display: block; }
label { font-family: sans-serif; }
input, textarea { font-family: monospace; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 1em; }
textarea { height: 15em; }
```

```html
<label for="input">Input (type to see changes)</label>
<input id="input" value='"paymentInfoList.paymentInfo(0).receiver.amount":"12.00"'/>
<label for="output">Output</label>
<textarea id="output">Click the "Parse!" button!</textarea>
```